# How can we run cron jobs for two different time intervals like - 5min, 5 min, 10 min, 5min, 5min, 10min

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have a script to run with cron in 5min for two times than in 10min...

This sequence should be continued... like. 5,5,10,5,5,10,5,5,10.....

How can we achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since a `{5, 5, 10}` gap cycle is 20 minutes (an nice integral factor of 60 minutes), I'd just opt for a crontab entry of:

```
0,5,10,20,25,30,40,45,50 * * * * * commandToExecute
```

Comment: Actually I have two script one is running in every 15 min and another should run after 5 min of the first script.... if I execute script as mentioned above (hardcoded nos) the both scripts clasing with each other....Could you suggest any solution?